# jquery serialize returns empty?

Tags: jquery, .net

i use jquery serialize but it returns empty string.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server"> 
<input name="kongreAd" type="text" />
..



 $("#aspnetForm").serialize();
```

it works on my local server but when i upload it to remote server, serialize method returns empty string. 
i use jquery 1.4.2 verison
whats the problem ?

Comment: which form are you serializing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no form with an ID of "aspnetForm" on your page. The id is "form1".

Comment: it is the general name of form and it works on my local server but it returns empty on remote.

Comment: You want $("#form1").serialize() or else you need to change the element to <form id="aspnetForm"...

Comment: Well, how do you expect it to serialize a form that has a different id. If there is only one form on the page try this for your selector. `$('form').serialize()`

Comment: But there is no id #aspnetForm in your example, so jquery can't select it. Seems u r missing something on your remote.

Comment: yes friends, you are right.. But how it work on my local i dont understand.
Thanks..

Comment: In general .NET wants to own all of the control IDs, so use class names instead. <form class="form1" runat="server">, then $(".form1").serialize();